# Disable adding page to navigation history on ExternalContext.redirect in JSF

Tags: jsf, redirect, xpages

I have requirement of using single page and passing parameters to handle redirects to different pages depending on prameters. I use following java code to redirect :

```
externalContext.redirect(targetUrl);
facesContext.responseComplete();
```

Page itself redirects fine, but whole site uses Xpages redirectToPrevious() method to handle "Back buttons", wchich seems to use latest page in navigation history. So long story short, i would like to dont add redirect page to navigation history. Is is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to kill the previous history entry with the *popPreviousUrl* method?

```
facesContext.getSessionData().popPreviousUrl()
```

Comment: I wasn't even aware that it is possible as designer don't even list these methods... Quality answer as always, thanks Sven!

Comment: Hmmm, is this xpages specific?

Comment: @Kukeltje: This seems to be IBM XPages specific